# RN-IOS Not loading images when build

Tags: ios, react-native

After upgrading the react native version(0.62.2), I tried to set up the system with the **react-native run-ios** but it doesn't load the assets (images)

*Application working fine
*Android working fine

What i tried;

1. Before build the system i removed ios/build folder everytime
2. Removed mainjs.bundle
3. react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'
4. Xcode "project name" > targets > build phases > Copy bundle resources try to add "assets" folder here
   [image]